# How to roll back on a recursive function that returns specific values

Tags: java, recursion, divide-and-conquer

Hello and thank you for your time and support.

My **generalized question** is: How should one roll back in a recursive function where specific values have to be returned?

My specific case:

In this problem, I have to check whether a given polynomial has any roots in a given interval, defined by it's margins: x1 and x2.

I have to do this by continuously halving the interval [x1,x2] until the difference between them is at most a value close to zero (for this value, I used the **foundroot** variable), in which case a root has been found.

This process is done by the recursive **findaroot** method with parameters x1 and x2 (the interval margins).

Here is how the method works:

1. The method first checks whether the value for **f(x1)** and **f(x2)** (the function's values in x1 and x2) have the same sign, in which case, there is no root in the interval, and returns the **noroot** value;
2. Then , it checks whether a root has been found (if **x1**-**x2**<=**foundroot**);
3. If a root has not been found, it returns minimum between the returned values for one of the intervals, **noroot** being a very high number in my case. Of course, this doesn't work if a root exceeds the value of **noroot**.

My **question** is:

- As the generalized question states, how should I make the method work for all cases, other than comparing the returned value with a high/low/not-easily-obtained number?

Here is my written code:

```
    //found root variable + value assigned if root is not found in interval (x1,x2)
    static final double foundroot = 0.000001;
    static final double noroot=999999;

    //finds root
    static double findaroot(double x1, double x2)
    {
        if(  Math.signum( f(x1,0) ) == Math.signum( f(x2,0) )  )
        {
            return noroot;
        }
        else
        {
            if(Math.abs(x1-x2)<=foundroot)
            {
                return x1;
            }
            else
            {
                return Math.min( findaroot(x1,(x1+x2)/2) , findaroot((x1+x2)/2,x2));
            }
        }
    }
```

If there's anything unclear, please ask. If you believe my questions/title are unspecific or unclear, please tell me how to modify them.

I will make clarifications as best I can to provide a clear description and, hopefully, a clear answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a magic number (no root), can be avoided by using a meaningful return value. In this case, you could consider switching to Double instead of double, and using the null value as a "no result" indicator.

This can be applied generically: If you are using recursive functions to calculate a certain outcome, but need to escape as well, using the null value is an acceptable escape. You could consider compound answers as well in case you need more than 1 escape (e.g. the reason for deciding no answer can be found). Use an object to construct your result in that case.

So in this case, alter your function to e.g.

```
static final double threshold = 0.000001;

//finds root; returns null if none is found
static Double findaroot(double x1, double x2)
{
    if(  Math.signum( f(x1,0) ) == Math.signum( f(x2,0) )  )
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        if(Math.abs(x1-x2)<=threshold)
        {
            return x1;
        }
        else
        {
            return Math.min( findaroot(x1,(x1+x2)/2) , findaroot((x1+x2)/2,x2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this answers my question, so I'll mark your answer as accepted. 

I changed the last else to `else {if(left half==null) {return right half} else {return left half}}` instead of `return Math.min(...)`.

Is there any way to modify this so the method doesn't run twice (once in the **if** and once in the **return**)?

Apologies for bad code, I can't seem to be able to post decent code in comments.